# Entry and exit 1 day before condition is met

Tags: pine-script

I am new to pine and am trying to test a simple MACD strategy. Thing is I want to enter and exit 1 day earlier in the backtesting.

```
//Strategy: Long when MACD line above Signal line and above SMA20 
if crossover(macdline, signalline)  
    // Buy when MACD crosses Signal from beneath
    strategy.entry("macd", long =true)
if crossunder(macdline, signalline) or crossunder(close, sma20) 
    // Sell when MACD crosses Signal from above or of closing price below MA20
    strategy.close("macd")
```

When you take a look at the enter and exit, they are actually one day later than the condition is met.

Any knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

That is because the [execution model](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Execution_model.html#) of the pinescript.

You can add `process_orders_on_close=true` to your `strategy()` call to execute orders after a bar closes and strategy calculations are completed.

```
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100, process_orders_on_close=true)
```